# Why does ip_forward=1 cause inadvertant problems?

Tags: linux-networking

I did a google search and searched the Ubuntu forums, but couldn't find the answer I was looking for with my specific situation. What I have is the following:

1. 2 handsets setup for VOIP communications with a VPN
2. The VPN as well as SIP servers are on a virtual network that is accessed via a wireless access point via wlan0 on a computer running Ubuntu.
3. I accidentally left enabled `ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and this was causing the call to drop after a few seconds. It took me some time with trial and error and flipping the flag off to determine that this was causing the problem.
4. With the flag on it caused some duplicate audio packets to be received which was flagged as an error by the receiving device.

   The results from searching the flag talk a lot about ip forwarding and what needs to be done to accomplish it, but not much in the way of problems that can be caused such as in my situation. Any ideas as to what happens with just this flag on?

Comment: An incorrect setting of `ip_forward` isn't your main problem. Your main problem is that something is producing those packets in the first place. The host which is not supposed to forward the packets shouldn't be receiving them in the first place. So you really need to identify why the packets got send to an incorrect host. Since silently dropping the stray packets make some of the symptoms go away, and since you observed duplicate packets in the first place, these are likely send both to the correct destination and to a wrong destination.

Comment: Most likely something is sending packets to a broadcast (or multicast) MAC address which cause them to be received both by the correct router and by another host which happened to be configured to forward them as well. Might you have configured a network broadcast address as the gateway for some route? (And did you really only write `ip_forward` in the config, or did it in fact say `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`?)

Comment: Thanks for the answers and sorry to get back to this so late. Yes, it was net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf. Everything's ok at the moment until I can dig into it further.